# Show a single column in a search result

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

Here is the mysql command:

``` SELECT * FROM ``wp_posts`` WHERE ``ID ``` `=` `17500`

which returns over 20 columns

How do I only display the `post_name` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = 17500`

More info about SELECT (Transact-SQL) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks @Ads.
I'll checkout the above link